# How to display a list of available goals?

Tags: maven-2

I'm rather new to Maven and I often find myself wanting to see what's actually *there* in terms of goals.

So, is there a command which lists all available goals for e.g. a given prefix?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Since Maven is an open system of plugins, the best answer is probably "Google" ;-). If you mean all build lifecycle phases, they are static, and can be found at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html and at other places.

Then, for a given plugin, the [help plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/index.html) can be used to get the possible goals and all their parameters:

```
mvn help:describe -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins \
                  -DartifactId=maven-war-plugin \
                  -Ddetail=true
```

But this doesn't really answer your question, especially the "for a given prefix" part. For this, the best solution might be to use **auto completion with BASH (**not sure it will be exhaustive though). See for example the [Guide to Maven 2.x auto completion using BASH](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-bash-m2-completion.html). To get bash completion working under Windows, you'll need CYGWIN. See [Maven Tab Auto Completion in Bash](http://willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=tabMaven) for detailed setup steps (and a "better" working auto completion script).

Comment: Thanks, that's some great information here. I figured out that you can also pass the 'detail' parameter (as in -Ddetail), which will print a list of all parameters plus description for a goal. Good stuff.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you find it useful. Regarding the `-Ddetail` parameter, you are absolutely right. Starting with version 2.1, it actually replaces the `-Dfull` from versions 2.0.x. I'll update my answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score 13):

#### A shorter way

As an alternative, you can also use the [`-Dplugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html#plugin) parameter to display the list of available goals.

```
mvn help:describe -Dplugin=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin\
                  -Ddetail=true
```

See [Maven help plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html#plugin).

Answer (score 7):

More and more Maven plugins propose an help goal as alternative to the verbose
`mvn help:describe` command.

You can read from the [Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html):

> Recent Maven plugins have generally an help goal to have in the
>   command line the description of the plugin, with their parameters and
>   types

That is really more natural and pleasant to use.

It works of course for **Maven core plugins**.
Some examples :

- to list goals of the `dependency` plugin :

  `mvn dependency:help`
- to have detail about the `javadoc` goal of the `javadoc` plugin :

  `mvn javadoc:help -Ddetail -Dgoal=javadoc`

And it works also for **third party plugins**.

For example, to list goals of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` :

```
mvn org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:help
```

> [INFO] Spring Boot Maven Plugin 2.0.0.RELEASE   Spring Boot Maven
>   Plugin
>
> This plugin has 6 goals:
>
> spring-boot:build-info
>
> Generate a build-info.properties file based the content of the
>   current   MavenProject.
>
> spring-boot:help
>
> Display help information on spring-boot-maven-plugin.   Call mvn
>   spring-boot:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal= to display
>   parameter details.
>
> spring-boot:repackage
>
> Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be
>   executed from the   command line using java -jar. With layout=NONE can
>   also be used simply to   package a JAR with nested dependencies (and
>   no main class, so not executable).
>
> .....

Or to get detailed information about the `build` goal of the `dockerfile-maven-plugin` :

```
mvn com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:help -Ddetail -Dgoal=build
```

> [INFO] Dockerfile Maven Plugin 1.3.6
>
> Adds support for building Dockerfiles in Maven
>
> dockerfile:build
>
> Available parameters:
>
> ```
> - archive
>
>   The archive configuration to use for the Docker info JAR. This can be used
>   to embed additional information in the JAR.
> ```
>
> ....

You could note that the syntax to get a detailed output of the help and to focus on a specific goal (`-Ddetail -Dgoal=myGoal`) is exactly the same as this used for the core maven plugins.

Of course some esoteric plugins may not provide the `help` goal but in most of well designed plugins this is present.

Answer (score 0):

To use `mvn help:describe ...` one needs to find the list of Maven plugins actually used by the project at hand.  Here is one way to collect the list:

```
workhorse:~/build/pulsar$ grep -A2 '<plugin>' -r --include pom.xml | perl -nle '$x{$1}=1 if /<artifactId>maven-(\w+)-plugin<\/artifactId>/; END {print "cd /"; for (sort keys %x) {print "mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=$_"}}' | tee saved-output
cd /
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=antrun
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=assembly
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=checkstyle
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=compiler
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=dependency
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=deploy
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=enforcer
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=jar
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=javadoc
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=resources
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=shade
mvn -B help:describe -Dplugin=surefire
```

Piping the output of the above command to a shell will yield the list of available goals (above the goals of the [three built-in lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)):

```
workhorse:~/build/pulsar$ sh saved-output | perl -nle '$|=1; print if /^Goal/../^For/' | less
Goal Prefix: antrun

This plugin has 2 goals:

antrun:help
  Description: Display help information on maven-antrun-plugin.
    Call mvn antrun:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=<goal-name> to display parameter
    details.

antrun:run
  Description: Maven AntRun Mojo. This plugin provides the capability of
    calling Ant tasks from a POM by running the nested ant tasks inside the
    <tasks/> parameter. It is encouraged to move the actual tasks to a separate
    build.xml file and call that file with an <ant/> task.

For more information, run 'mvn help:describe [...] -Ddetail'
Goal Prefix: assembly

This plugin has 8 goals:

assembly:assembly
...
```

Notes:

1. Every `mvn help:describe ...` takes up to 30s, use patience
2. I have used `\w+` not `\S+` to match plugin name so as to avoid security risk of feeding arbitrary character sequence extracted from third party code to my shell
3. `mvn help:describe` didn't work for me in a project directory with a `pom.xml` in it.  I worked around by `cd /`
4. I am a stranger to Java and Maven, the answer may be incomplete but hopefully still useful.