# Build the pom file to download the dependencies with eclipse

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I download a j2ee project with a pom file which mention the dependency jar files needed. I want to know to run this pom file and download the jars need for my project? I right click and ran the pom file as maven build. Then it prompt me the Edit and Configuration UI which has the goals and profiles.

What are the values that i need to specify here?

Also is there any special configuration i need to add to eclipse (helios)?

How does the necessary jar files downloaded? Is it from the `xsi:schemaLocation` location specify in the pom file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these maven goals for that.

*eclipse:eclipse* - Download the dependency jars and set them to the classpath(you need to configure your settings.xml in the maven with the maven archiva repo path for maven to download jars from there)

*install* - build the project and install it in the local repo.

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996866/2024761) for the whole list of goals.

Comment: you also mentioned about m2e plugin right? how to configure settings.xml? i dont find a setting.xml file

Answer (score 0):

IF you install the Maven to Eclipse integration plugin (m2e), Eclipse will automagically add the project dependencies to the project's build path, and download them in the process.

Comment: i install and try the m2e. i mentioned "clean install" in the goal in the maven run configuration window. Before doing it i convert the project to maven project with using eclipse. The Maven Dependency variable show in build path too. But i cant see the jars already downloaded when i expand that. So my project source still gives compile errors because the jars which downloaded to my local repository is not show in my project build path. can you please help me on this? thank you